# fedprox tensorflow federated (TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable LearningProcessOutput object)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

```
iterative_process = tff.learning.algorithms.build_unweighted_fed_prox( 
    model_fn,
    proximal_strength= 0.5,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0))

state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
print('round  1, metrics={}'.format(metrics))
```

On executing the round 1, it throws  (TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable LearningProcessOutput object).

It was working fine when we use Fedavg, but not with fedprox

Answer (score 1):

`iterative_process.next` returns [`LearningProcessOutput`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/d43bb1204ae66d5021146cacb8056ae73db7d80c/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/templates/learning_process.py#L53) which is not iterable, as the error says.

You can replace it by

```
output = iterative_process.next(...)
state = output.state
metrics = output.metrics
```

or just use the `output` directly.